# Difference between general visual inspection and pre-flight check inspection

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, preflight

I know the definition of [general visual inspection (GVI)](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/IP122%20Rev%202.pdf) but I cannot understand the differences (if there are) with a pre-flight check inspection.

I am new in the field and I am not a pilot (don't worry...) but I would be glad if anyone could clarify this for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GVI is a maintenance procedure that has to be performed by a mechanic qualified to do so, to satisfy a Maintenance Program requirement, and which will require a maintenance release to be signed off.

A pre-flight inspection is an inspection performed by a pilot in command (or someone delegated by the PIC - like a First Officer, or a mechanic) to satisfy the PIC that the aircraft is safe for flight.

The pre-flight, being a look-over to make sure nothing has fallen off, is dribbling fluid, or is flat, is going to be more superficial than a GVI and usually doesn't involve getting your hands dirty (at airlines it's usually done by the First Officer while in uniform) and normally doesn't involve opening access panels or doors (but could).  Also the pre-flight is a whole-aircraft once-over while a GVI is usually system or zone specific in keeping with its Maintenance Program objectives.

Answer (score 1):

Preflight may consist items which are GVI in its nature. But the difference is how regulations treats such inspection (preflight). As per Commission Regulation (EU) No 1321/2014 **Pre-flight is not considered to be *maintenance***:

> (h) ‘maintenance’ means any one or combination of the following activities: overhaul, repair, inspection, replacement, modification or defect rectification of an aircraft or component, **with the exception of pre-flight inspection**;

and thus:

> (d) The pilot-in-command or, in the case of commercial air transport, the operator shall be responsible for the satisfactory accomplishment of the pre-flight inspection. *This inspection must be carried out by the pilot or another qualified person **but need not be carried out by an approved maintenance organisation or by Part-66 certifying Staff**.*